# How to perform arithmetic on two class instances (with float as a subclass) which return a class instance of the same type? e.g. Speed(2) + Speed(2)

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance, subclass

How to perform arithmetic on classes with a basic type as a subclass, where the result is of the same class?

For example, running:

```
class Speed(float):

    def __add__(self, speed):
        if isinstance(speed, Speed):
            return Speed(self + speed)
        else:
            raise NotImplementedError()

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Speed({self} mph)'

Speed(2) + Speed(2)
```

Results in the below instead of the expected `Speed(4)`:

```
RecursionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-ce1336693f4a> in <module>
----> 1 Speed(2) + Speed(2)

<ipython-input-11-f161664be9bc> in __add__(self, speed)
      3     def __add__(self, speed):
      4         if isinstance(speed, Speed):
----> 5             return Speed(self + speed)
      6         else:
      7             raise NotImplementedError()

... last 1 frames repeated, from the frame below ...

<ipython-input-11-f161664be9bc> in __add__(self, speed)
      3     def __add__(self, speed):
      4         if isinstance(speed, Speed):
----> 5             return Speed(self + speed)
      6         else:
      7             raise NotImplementedError()

RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

How to correctly perform arithmetic on such a class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert both `self` and `speed` to float before handing it to the `+` operator, because otherwise it will try to call the method again on one of the `Speed` instances. This will happen recursively without bail condition and eventually err out as it did in your case.

```
return Speed(float(self) + float(speed))
```